# Populating and repopulating select dropdown codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, select, repopulation

I would like to populate a select dropdown using codeigniter `form_dropdown` for that I have written below code in my `view`:

```
                 $experience = array(
                    "" => "- Min Exp -",
                    "0" => "Freshers & &lt;1 Yr",
                    "1" => "1 Yr",
                    "2" => "2 Yrs",
                    "3" => "3 Yrs",
                    "4" => "4 Yrs",
                    "5" => "5 Yrs",
                    "6" => "6 Yrs"
                );

$js = 'id="minexp" style="width: 95%;padding-top: 7px" required';
echo form_dropdown('minexp', $experience, $this->input->post('minexp'), $js);
```

The repopulating is working perfect, but by default it is selecting the `Freshers & &lt;1 Yr` and I would like to have `- Min Exp -` as selected when the user views the page first time.

Any help or suggestion would be a great help.. I googled and not found any solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking if the post data is there first.

```
echo form_dropdown('minexp', $experience, (($this->input->post('minexp')) ? $this->input->post('minexp') : ''), $js);
```

Comment: Or `$this->input->post('minexp') ?: ''` for PHP 5.3+

Comment: @786 If you need more explanation, let me know :)

Comment: thank you very much @HashemQolami Sir... i got it perfectly..no dauds.. :)